# How to track and zoom in AE

Tags: after-effects

I want to learn how to make the effect that is presented in the video from 0:29 to 0:31, that is, cursor tracking and zoom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

- Track the cursor in After-Effects (using the tracking-panel)
- Apply the movement to a Null-Object
- Create a camera
- Parent the camera to the Null
- Change the focal length in the camera to achieve the zoom

Now your camera should follow the cursor.